# Column sum in torch

Tags: torch

How do i sum along a column in torch? I have a 128*1024 tensor, and I want to get a 1*1024 tensor by summing all the rows.

For example:
a:

`1  2  3
 4  5  6`

I want b

`5 7 9`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To do this, you can use the sum method.

`torch.sum(a,1)`

In general, you can specify any axis you want to sum over.

`torch.sum(a,axis)`

(To sum over rows, you can use axis=2)